# Docker run - unable to find image locally, even though docker images show it exists

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am learing The Ways of The Whale:) and I am currently trying to start the image that I have just built:

`docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name brrname hyenatest:bb`

The response is

> Unable to find image 'hyenatest:bb' locally
> docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for hyenatest, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

when I run `docker images` command, **I see my image being there**:

[image]

**When I run the command with my image ID, it works OK**:

`docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name brrname b76c26b5bed3`

Why does it only work based on image ID?

Cheers,

Comment: Just making sure it's not a typo ... you're trying to run hyenatest:bb and your image name is heyna (instead of hyena).

Answer (score 1):

In your run command you're typing `hyenatest`, but the repository name is `heynatest`.

Comment: Cannot believe it. Who picked this project name??? :)